# Why would using Combine's `catch` cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: swift, segmentation-fault, combine

I've just spent far too long trying to fix a release build because of a segmentation fault 11.

In the end the code change was from this...

```
fetchValue
    .receive(on: scheduler)
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
    .sink { [weak self] completion in
        switch completion {
        case .failure(let error):
            self?.state = .error(error.localizedDescription)
        case .finished:
            return
        }
    } receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
        self?.state = .someValue(value)
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

to this...

```
fetchValue
    .map(State.someValue)
    .catch { error in Just(State.error(error.localizedDescription)) }
    .receive(on: scheduler)
    .assign(to: \.state, on: self)
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

And specifically it was the `catch` line that was causing the issue.

In the above `fetchValue` is defined as a `Future<SomeValue, Error>`.

And `self.state` is defined as an enum like...

```
enum State {
  case someValue(SomeValue)
  case error(String)
}
```

It built for debug and testing with no issues at all.

But when building for release (archiving) with Xcode 13.0 and 13.1 it caused a segmentation fault 11 and I just have no idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use an instance method instead a static one to map the enum ?

```
fetchValue
    .map(State.someValue)
```

---

```
fetchValue
    .map { State.someValue($0) }
```

Comment: I didn't. I'll give that a go and report back. Do you think that would make a difference in this case? Thanks

Comment: It's one of differences with previous version. It's also rare to use a static method with map so maybe it's a Swift bug.